# WCF stream.Read behavior

Tags: .net, wcf, stream

Scenario: There's a WCF streamed service that provides file streams to clients. On the client side, the WCF file stream is being read by calling stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize), where chunkSize is 10240.

I wonder if data is being transferred over the network (internet) only when a call to Read is made, or there's something reading data in the background and potentially data is already read when a call to stream.Read is made. I'm asking this because I need to measure download speed. But, after I read a chunk of data, I perform other operations - sending out events, writing data just read to a local file stream. Therefore, I need to discount these other operations, so that I have a clear picture of how long it took to download the file only. So I keep measuring how long it takes to download 10KB of data and in the end kbsPerSecond is calculated using the total file size and total time elapsed.

Unfortunately, having a stopwatch within a loop causes a performance penalty, but I guess I'll have to live with it if I want to measure bandwidth correctly.

```
long totalBytesRead = 0;
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

do
{
    int bytesRead;

    stopwatch.Start();
    bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    if (bytesRead == 0)
        break;

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

    // 1. write to local file stream
    // 2. raise file download progress events

} while (true);

long elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
int kbsPerSecond = Convert.ToInt32(((double)totalBytesRead / 1024) / ((double)elapsedTime / 1000));
```

Would this approach be accurate?

Answer (score 3):

Have you measured the actual performance impact of the stopwatch?  I just ran a quick test on my machine (so YMMV) with an outer stopwatch to measure total time, and a stopwatch inside a loop to simulate the one you are using.  The loop iterated one million times and the total performance impact of the inner stopwatch was a mere 49 milliseconds (spread across all 1 million iterations), so you're talking low single digit ticks per iteration.

Unless you're seeing a larger impact, it doesn't look like you need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that approach would be fairly accurate, given that the other stuff you're doing inside the loop is pretty minimal..

you might be able to improve the ratio of useful:non-useful time in the loop by downloading longer streams, and by increasing the chunkSize

also, checking if bytesRead == 0 and incrementing totalBytesRead is likely to take very little time indeed, I'd suggest that the calls to stopwatch.start/stop take longer - you could move those calls outside of the loop

Answer (score 0):

**If** you need a truly accurate timing of the time it takes to read the stream for some reason (Why you would need such a high level of accuracy is unclear), why not isolate the read code altogether and only call it once by reading the contents into a really large buffer (If you know the content size you are reading from the stream, you can use that):

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[int.MaxValue]; // Alternatively, enter the size of the content
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
int totalBytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
stopwatch.Stop();
long elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
double kbsPerSecond = ((double)totalBytesRead / 1024) / ((double)elapsedTime / 1000);
```

However, if this is production code and you are trying to measure real life timings, then your approach is correct and the extra time taken to make the Stop and Start methods is negligible when compared to the time taken to read from a stream.